# Ros topics over different computer

Tags: ros, keyboard-teleop, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a turtlebot running ROS-Electric, and remote laptop also running ROS-Electric.

I was trying to publish message to rostopic /cmd_vel, in order to control velocity of turtlebot from remote laptop. However I noticed that, messages published in remote laptop is visible (via rostopic echo) only in remote laptop and not on turtlebot laptop. However I can read the data published by keyboard_teleop running turtlebot, on remote laptop. keyboard_teleop works when it is run on turtlebot laptop, and not on remote laptop. Why is this so? Here ROS_MASTER_URI has been properly configured to point turtlebot laptop.

I was expecting the communication to happen across multiple computer as ROS master is running on turtlebot, and takes care of the networking for ROS topics. Can anybody kindly explain how we can publish to a rostopic subscribed on another computer?

Thanks
Subhash

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37202/ros-topics-over-different-computer/) by [Subhash](https://answers.ros.org/users/2594/subhash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should check your network setup and make sure, that both laptops are able to ping each other by the name you have set as ROS_HOSTNAME.
If you have not set ROS_HOSTNAME, try setting ROS_IP to the interface adresses you are using for the networkcommunication.

You can do this by adding the following line to your .bashrc:

```
export ROS_IP=10.1.1.xxx
```

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been asked (and answered) multiple times already. E.g. [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/9679/nodes-with-2-computers/) or [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/31418/communicating-with-turtlebot-from-two-computers/). Also please have a look at the [support guidelines](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3